# Measure spaces that stabilize with respect to the Carathéodory extension

Tags: measure-theory, outer-measure

When learning measure theory, for sure one encounters the Carathéodory extension theorem with extends a premeasure defined over a semiring to a measure defined over a $\sigma-$algebra. Let $X$ be a set, $\mathcal{R}$ be a semiring over $X$ and $\mu$ be a premeasure defined over $\mathcal{R}$.

For me, a natural question is: what if we apply the Carathéodory extension a second time to the measure space $(X,\mathcal{R}',\mu')$ itself obtained by the Carathéodory extension of $(X,\mathcal{R},\mu)$? Fortunately, the result stabilizes, because the outer measure induced by $\mu$ and $\mu'$ are the same: for any subset $S\subset X$ we have

$$\mu^*(S)\overset{\operatorname{def}}{=}\inf\left\{\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\mu(A_n):A_n\in\mathcal{R},\bigcup^{\infty}_{n=1}A_n\supset S\right\}=\inf\{\mu'(A):A\in\mathcal{R}',A\supset S\},$$

where $\mu^*$ is the outer measure induced by $\mu$. Clearly we have "$\ge$" since $\displaystyle\bigcup^{\infty}_{n=1}A_n\in\mathcal{R}'$ and that $\displaystyle\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\mu(A_n)\ge\mu'\left(\displaystyle\bigcup^{\infty}_{n=1}A_n\right)$. For "$\le$", note that $\mu'(A)=\mu^*(A)\ge\mu^*(S)$ for every $A\in\mathcal{R}'$.

So I would like to ask: is there a name designed for the measure spaces with the property "unable to be further extended by the Carathéodory process"? Are there any easy criteria to determine whether a measure space has such property?

Comment: At least for $\sigma$-finite measure spaces, completeness (every subset of a null set is measurable) should suffice.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Thanks! And it's a pity that a great number of measures encountered in real life are not $\sigma-$finite (for example the $s-$dimensional Hausdorff measure over $\mathbb{R}^d$ for $s\in[0,d)$) :)

Comment: I'm not whether $\sigma$-finiteness is even needed. There are a bunch of weakenings (like strict localizability) that should suffice "in practice".

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Thank you for your comment. I would like to add that a counterexample would be the cocountable measure (where the only measurable sets are either countable or cocountable), which is complete but whose Carathéodory extension is defined in the whole space. Of course this is not an interesting example.

Comment: That specifies the $\sigma$-algebra. What is the measure?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker The one that sends countable sets to $0$ and the uncountable sets to $\infty$.